# How to define a 'concept' that uses a 'concept' in C++ 20?

Tags: c++, c++20, metaprogramming, c++-concepts

I am studying `concepts` in C++ 20, and came up with the need of defining a `concept` using a previous defined `concept`.

So, in the example below I expected `f<pub_b>()` to generate a compiler error, since `events_published` in `pub_b` does not satisfy `publisher` concept, as `ev_2` does not satisfy `event` concept.

It seems that using `event` concept in `publisher` concept has no effect.

`g++ version` reports

```
g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <concepts>
#include <tuple>

template <typename t>
concept event = requires {
  std::default_initializable<t>;
  std::copy_constructible<t>;
  std::move_constructible<t>;
};

struct ev_1 {
  ev_1() = default;
  ev_1(const ev_1 &) = default;
  ev_1(ev_1 &&) = default;
};

struct ev_2 {
  ev_2() = delete;
  ev_2(const ev_2 &) = default;
  ev_2(ev_2 &&) = default;
};

template <typename t>
concept publisher = requires {
  typename t::events_published;

  requires[]<std::size_t... t_idx>(std::index_sequence<t_idx...>) {
    return ((event<typename std::tuple_element_t<
                 t_idx, typename t::events_published>>)&&...);
  }
  (std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<typename t::events_published>>());
};

struct pub_a {
  using events_published = std::tuple<ev_1>;
};

struct pub_b {
  using events_published = std::tuple<ev_2>;
};

template <publisher t_publisher> void f() {}

int main() {
  f<pub_a>();

  f<pub_b>();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `event` `concept` requires more `requires`:

```cpp
template <typename t>
concept event = requires {
    requires std::default_initializable<t>;
    requires std::copy_constructible<t>;
    requires std::move_constructible<t>;
};
```

```cpp
int main() {
    f<pub_a>();

    //f<pub_b>(); // Now gives a compilation error
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to use a `requires`-clause for your concept as it is usually used to check the validity of an expression. Just simply

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename t>
concept event = std::default_initializable<t> &&
                std::copy_constructible<t>;
```

as `copy_constructible` already guarantees `move_constructible`. If you also need the type to be copy-assignable, life will be easier

```
template <typename t>
concept event = std::semiregular<t>;
```